# Hadoop-streaming : PYTHONPATH not working when mapper runs

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

- I have a PYTHONPATH set up in and it works fine too except when I run map-reduce job
- It fails saying

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/work/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/taskTracker/hduser/jobcache/job_201203091218_0006/attempt_201203091218_0006_m_000020_0/work/./mapper.py", line 57, in 
      from src.utilities import utilities
  ImportError: No module named src.utilities
  java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
      at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:311)
      at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:545)
      at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.map(PipeMapper.java:121)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
      at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:36)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:261)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
      at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:255)
  java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
      at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:311)
      at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:545)
      at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:132)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:57)
      at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:36)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:261)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
      at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:255)

**Question:**
- Is it that during hadoop-streaming we have to setup Python path specifically? where?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I think the problem is that the Hadoop virtual environments won't recognize your system's pythonpath. If you install packages to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages, Hadoop will pick them up and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

we need to add MapReduce Service Environment Safety Valve, In mycase we are using cloudera-manager GUI, I added PYTHONPATH it's working.